# Foursquare KML feed shows ONLY recent posts

Tags: url, dictionary, kml, feed, foursquare

For years, I had been using my Foursquare KML url to populate a Google Map that I then placed on my website.

A few months ago, I noticed that the feed would not load check-ins in the feed for earlier events and instead only the recent check-ins. The result has been a near empty map that goes back only a few months rather than 4 years.

I've checked with support many times over the past 6-7 months and the response is always quite general. Nobody has actually looked at my account to see what the issue is.

And the last response was to come here and ask you all.

So that's my issue:

- The Foursquare KML feed only will populate a map with recent check-ins.
- I've refreshed the feed URLs on the foursuare.com/feeds page and tried with that new url
- When I go into my Foursquare.com/user/history page on a desktop, all my check-ins are there and are populated on that map which uses Mapbox/OpenStreetMaps.

If anyone has any advice as to how to get this problem fixed, please let me know. And if someone knows of a work-around to instead get whatever feed Foursqure is using to populate Mapbox/OpenStreetMaps, that would work great too!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `?count=500` to your KML feed URL? By default it seems limited to the last 10.